# Running python flask gunicorn app from shell script

Tags: python, shell, flask, gunicorn

I build my flask app, it requires external files through the runtime.
when I build the app, meaning I run > gunicorn app:app (the app startup file is called app.py but that didn't bother). It runs awesomely.
Now when I decided to make a sort of shell script to execute it (actually to make a couple of dependencies and environment checking but for the sake of simplifying, I created startup.sh in the same directory as app.py and it contains only the following instruction unquoted: "gunicorn app:app"), it just throws errors.
and this is the last one ...

[image]
Please help..

Comment: well, it turns out the first time it ran under python 3.6.5, but when launched from within the shell script it ran with 2.7 for which there are missing dependencies ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yep just as I guessed, it should be run within the script inside a virtualenv so that it will execute python 3 :)